# c# Setting text to = a name from a database

Tags: c#, mysql

I am looking to set the text of label1 to equal what is found in the DB at position 2 but for some reason instead of running the sql it tries to set the text to equal the double value

```
private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double count = 2;
    label1.Text = table1TableAdapter.GetData(count);
}
```

The SQL in the table adapter:

```
SELECT Name FROM Table1 WHERE (ID = COUNT)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it tries to set the text to equal the double value"? What is the exact type of `table1TableAdapter`? What is the return type of the `GetData` method?

Comment: Shouldn't `COUNT` be a variable in the sql statement? (I'm not familiar with mySql syntax for variables) `SELECT Name FROM Table1 WHERE (ID = COUNT)`

Answer (score 2):

```
double count = 2;
var lblVal = table1TableAdapter.GetData((int)count);
label1.Text = lblVal.ToString();
```

Get the value, then assign it.

Comment: I think no need to set into var datatype first, we can directly do with single line of code.

Comment: You are correct, it was more for debugging purposes.

Comment: Thank you i am now getting this error       An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Could not find file 'C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication8\WindowsFormsApplication8\bin\Debug

Comment: The exception indicates an error with your datasource... look at your connection string or permissions...

Comment: when i try and save the SQL in the Query builder i get the following message                                                                                                          Error in WHERE clause near ')'.
Unable to parse query text.

Comment: Can you post the SQL query?

Comment: SELECT        Name
FROM            Table1
WHERE        (ID = COUNT)

Comment: Does it display 'COUNT' in the query or '2'?

Comment: When i change the code to Where (id=2) it runs   and Count

Comment: You need to pass the value of count to the query and not the name 'count'

Comment: try make sure the count is an integer value

Comment: this is my code      private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int count = 2;
            var lblVal = table1TableAdapter.GetData1(count);
            label1.Text = lblVal.ToString();
        }

Comment: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter '' of 'Table1TableAdapter.GetData1(Database2DataSet.Table1DataTable, int)'.

Comment: did you add the (int)?

Comment: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'WindowsFormsApplication8.Database2DataSet.Table1DataTable' WindowsFormsApplication8

Answer (score 2):

```
private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double count = 2;
    label1.Text = table1TableAdapter.GetData((int)count).ToString();
}
```